# Find Prime strings using given definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the purpose of this problem, redefine the word "divides" to apply to strings over {a,b} such that D(u,v) means "u is a substring of v" or equivalently $\exists x:\exists y: = xuy = v$. As with the naturals, we redefine the word "prime" for strings so that P(w) means "if D(x,w) is true, then either x = empty string  or x = w.

What strings are "prime" using this definition?

Explain why any string factors uniquely as a product of these primes.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Which of the following are "prime": $a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, abc$?

Comment: Would it be a,b,bb,aa?

Comment: $a$ is a substring of $aa$ which is neither empty not the whole string, and similarly $b$ a substring of $bb$ etc. So $aa, bb$ can't be "prime".

Comment: The definition of "prime" could have been a little more careful, though: as it stands, the empty string is "prime" :) But all the other "prime" strings have one big feature in common, in which they differ from the empty string.

Comment: Doesn't bb have substrings b and b?  What strings won't have substrings?  This is ... not open to much misinterpretation?

Comment: so a, b and the empty string...

Comment: @BrianO Why is the empty string being prime a problem?  Isn't xyzabc considered the same as xyz\*$\emptyset$\*abc so that wouldn't that still be a unique "prime factorization".

Comment: Aye. I think whoever concocted the question wanted it to exclude the empty string, because if $\varepsilon$ is "prime" then factorization is **not** unique :) So emend the definition to exclude $\varepsilon$. Like this: $P(w) \iff w \neq \varepsilon \text{ and } \forall x\:(D(x,w) \to (x = \varepsilon \vee x = w))$, and work with *that*. Make it clear in your writeup that you're doing so & why.

Comment: @fleablood factorization won't be unique: $a = \varepsilon a = a \varepsilon \varepsilon = ...$. Given a string $s$, there are multiple ways to write $s$ as a product of "primes". This is why $1$ is not considered a prime in the integers.

Comment: (@ OP) What would the "primes" be if the alphabet were, say, $\{a,b,c\}$? Either definition.

Comment: a,b,c and the empty string

Comment: Right, you got it. In short, a string is "prime" if it has no proper nontrivial "divisors" i.e. no proper substrings except the empty string. In short, it's length is ≤ 1.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!